# how to be back to previous VC or next VC from a view controller inside UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers that controlled by UIPageViewController like the image below

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lqoj.png

if I swipe the screen, it will move from RedVC to BlueVC and to YellowVC.

I want make next button and back button **in the BlueVC**. so if the user press  the back button, it will go to RedVC, and if the user press the next button, it will go to YellowVC. how to do that ?

here is my code in the root page view controller:

```
import UIKit

class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    lazy var viewControllerList : [UIViewController] = {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let redVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "redVC")
        let blueVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blueVC")
        let yellowVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yellowVC")

        return [redVC,blueVC,yellowVC]
    }() 


    // to add dot indicator
    var pageControl = UIPageControl()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        configurePageControl()
        turnIntoPage()

    }




    func turnIntoPage() {
        // set view controllers to be pages

        if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first {
            // if so then set the direction
            self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }




    // MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source functions
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        // a method that will handle view controller before current view controller

        // make precaution , if the lodic is wrong then return nil (prevent index out of logic)
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController) else { return nil}
        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil}
        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else {return nil}


        // return the value
        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
    }


    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        // a method that will handle view controller after current view controller

        // make precaution , if the lodic is wrong then return nil (prevent index out of logic)
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController) else { return nil}
        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1
        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else {return nil}
        guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else {return nil}

         // return the value
        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]


    }




     // to add dot indicator


    // MARK: Page View Controller Delegate functions
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
        self.pageControl.currentPage = viewControllerList.index(of: pageContentViewController)!
    }


    func configurePageControl() {

        // The total number of pages that are available is based on how many available colors we have.
        pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 50,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = viewControllerList.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in your `RootPageViewController`, you could have a function there that will use `setViewControllers`.

And that `setViewControllers` is described as:

> // Set visible view controllers, optionally with animation. Array
>   should only include view controllers that will be visible after the
>   animation has completed.
>       // For transition style 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl', if 'doubleSided' is
>   'YES' and the spine location is not
>   'UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid', two view controllers must be
>   included, as the latter view controller is used as the back.

So let's try to have a `Next` function.

```
func next() {
    let vcs = self.viewControllerList
    //or self.viewControllers
    let currentPage = self.pageControl.currentPage
    let nextPage = currentPage + 1

    if nextPage < vcs.count {
        let nextVC = vcs[nextPage]
        self.setViewControllers([nextVC], direction: .forward, animated: true) { _ in
            self.pageControl.currentPage = nextPage
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are safely getting a viewController from the `vcs` you made in your code, which contains all the pages. And after we get the next viewController, if there's any, we use the `setViewControllers`. To make it better, we're setting the `currentPage` of your `pageControl` to tell which circle at the bottom of your pageController to be colored.

And then from your `BlueVC`, get a reference of your pageController. How? By accessing the `self.parent` and cast it as your `RootPageViewController`. Like so:

```
@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
    if let parentVC = self.parent as? RootPageViewController {
        parentVC.next()
    }
}
```

Now, it's your task to implement the `previous` function.